# Use a static library with Objective-C code on Windows

Tags: objective-c, windows, cocoa-touch

I'm developing for Cocoa-(touch) and will write a file using UIDocument. The problem is, that I have to open this file on Windows platform as well. Is that theoretical possible?

One idea was to create a static library including a subclass of UIDocument (Objective-C) and a C++ Wrapper. But can I use this library on windows?

Would be perfect, if someone can help me here or post some helpful links. Up do now, I couldn't find anything helpful using the search function.

Comment: Do you mean the document file created by your program has to be opened on a windows system, or your code itself has to run on both systems?

Answer (score 0):

You can try GNUStep, http://www.gnustep.org/.